# Error running react native app - Check the render method of `App`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am getting below error when trying to run react native expo app.

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.
>
> This error is located at:
> in App (created by ExpoRoot)
> in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
> in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:121)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
> in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39) at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in
> reportException at
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19
> in handleException at
> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in
> handleError at
> node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in
> ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0 at [native code]:null in
> flushedQueue at [native code]:null in
> invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue

App.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import HomeStack from './routes/homeStack';

const getFonts = () => Font.loadAsync({
  'poppins-regular' : require('./assets/fonts/poppins/Poppins-Regular.otf'),
});

export default function App() {
const [fontsLoaded , setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);

if(fontsLoaded) {
 return (
   <HomeStack />
 );
} else {

  return (
   <AppLoading
   startAsync={getFonts}
   onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)}
   />
  );
  }
}
```

homeStack.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from '../screens/login';
import Dashboard from '../screens/dashboard';


const screens = {
 Login: {
     screen: Login
 },
 Dashboard: {
     screen: Dashboard
 }
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);

export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

Comment: You need to return the `AppContainer` from a class, or a functional component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `AppContainer` from the `homeStack.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from '../screens/login';
import Dashboard from '../screens/dashboard';

export default class HomeStack extends Component{
  render(){
     return <AppContainer />
     }
}

const screens = {
 Login: {
     screen: Login
 },
 Dashboard: {
     screen: Dashboard
 }
}

const homeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(homeStack);
```

Comment: Tried this, but it is throwing error, Identifier 'HomeStack' has already been declared.

Comment: @jack Ohh sorry! I didn't see you have already used the name `HomeStack`

Comment: Thanks, but its again throwing the same error which it was throwing previously.

Comment: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of App.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```js
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
```

like it is written in the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v45.0.0/sdk/app-loading/) ?

`Apploading` is the doc is imported like a default export, but you are importing it as a named export. Typescript would be warning you, I think.

Because since there is not default export, `Apploading` is `undefined`.